# Access first part of hash value?

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash that looks like the following:

```
my %parameters= (
RamSize => "1000"
PageSize => "200, 200"
SysClock => "1"
);
```

I need to access PageSize id of this hash but I need to access this as 200 and 200 separately rather than "200, 200".  I cannot change how this is input so what is the easiest way to access it as 200?

Comment: That's not valid Perl. Please fix!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have written isn't valid Perl. Your hash presumably looks like this

```
my %parameters = (
    RamSize  => "1000",
    PageSize => "200, 200",
    SysClock => "1",
);
```

The element `$parameters{PageSize}` is a simple string, and you have to process it explicitly to extract substrings from it.

It's unclear what you might need in the general case, but if you simply want all integer values that appear in the string then a global regex match will do that for you. Like this

```
my ($ps1, $ps2) = $parameters{PageSize} =~ /\d+/g;

say $ps1;
say $ps2;
```

#### output

```
200
200
```

Answer (score 1):

What you posted doesn't make sense. I'm assuming you actually have the following:

```
my %parameters = (
    RamSize  => "1000",
    PageSize => "200, 200",
    SysClock => "1",
);
```

If so, you can use the following:

```
my ($x, $y) = split /\s*,\s*/, $parameters{PageSize};
```